# Чи існує слово "збільши"?

Tags: дієслова, дієвідмінювання, spelling, милозвучність

Чи дійсно існує слово "збільши"?

Slovnyk.ua для наказового способу пропонує лише слово "[збільш](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%C7%C1%B2%CB%DC%D8%C8%D2%C8)":

```
         ОДНИНА  МНОЖИНА
1 особа          збільшмо
2 особа  збільш  збільште
```

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, додайте до свого запитання що ви шукали і яких висновків ви вже дійшли (я додав те, що могло на мою думку поліпшити питання - якщо незгодні відредагуйте за допомогою [edit]). Почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання.

Comment: [Ось тут це слово є](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), але словник 1929 року.

Comment: @Yola, перепрошую, але там «збільши́», а не «збі́льши». У випадку наголосу на «и», [проблем немає](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par81p1a). А от із наголосом на корені воно начебто вже має бути лише без «и».

Answer (score 9):

Згідно до «Українського правопису 2015» (якщо трактувати його буквально) — **ні**.

На практиці — можливо, й так, хтозна.

#### Правопис

[§ 81](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par81) каже так (мій переказ):

1. Якщо в наказовому способі **наголос падає на закінчення** або виконуються деякі інші умови (не стосується даного питання: префікс *ви-*, суфікс *-ну-*, основа закінчується на <довільна приголосна> + <*л* чи *р*>) — то закінчення починається з голосної: *біж**и́***, *біж**і́**ть*, *біж**і́**м(о)* — а не <s>*біж*</s>, <s>*біжте*</s>, <s>*біжм(о)*</s>.

   <sub>«Правописний словник» Голоскевича (1929), що фіксує явно застарілі наголоси в деяких формах слів *[збільшити](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&scope=ukr&dicts=11)*, *[зменшити](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&scope=ukr&dicts=11)*, наводить відповідно і наказові форми з голосною в закінченні: *збільш**и́***, *збільш**і́**ть*; *зменш**и́***, *зменш**і́**ть* (зверніть увагу на нетипові наголоси).</sub>
2. **В інших випадках** за правописом закінчення не починається з голосної: *рі́ж*, *рі́жте*, *рі́жмо* — а не <s>*ріж**и***</s>, <s>*ріж**і**ть*</s>, <s>*ріж**і**мо*</s>.

Відповідно до цієї схеми, якщо не застосовувати нетипові наголоси, то:

- *збільш*, *збільште*, *збільшмо* — а не <s>*збі́льши*</s>, <s>*збі́льшіть*</s>, <s>*збі́льшімо*</s>;
- *зменш*, *зменште*, *зменшмо* — а не <s>*зме́нши*</s>, <s>*зме́ншіть*</s>, <s>*зме́ншімо*</s>;
- *чисть*, *чистьте*, *чистьмо* — а не <s>*чи́сти*</s>, <s>*чи́стіть*</s>, <s>*чи́стімо*</s>;
- <sub>*засвідч*, *засвідчте*, *засвідчмо* — а не <s>*засві́дчи*</s>, <s>*засві́дчіть*</s>, <s>*засві́дчімо*</s>;</sub>
- <sub>*підтвердь*, *підтвердьте*, *підтвердьмо* — а не <s>*підтве́рди*</s>, <s>*підтве́рдіть*</s>, <s>*підтве́рдімо*</s></sub>.

#### Практика

Якщо правильні за правописом *збільш/зменш* вживаються в книжках справді частіше, ніж *збільши/зменши* (хоча останні, на мій погляд, зовсім не ріжуть слух навіть при наголосі на першому складі), то із правильними за правописом *збільште/зменште* повна біда — вони де-факто трапляються в книжках рідше, ніж неправильні за правописом *збільшіть/зменшіть*: [21 *збільште*](//www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%22) + [12 *зменште*](//www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%22) проти [54 *збільшіть*](//www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C%22) + [46 *зменшіть*](//www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C%22).

Навіть правильне за правописом слово *чистьте* трапляється в книжках рідше за неправильне за правописом *чистіть* ([20](//www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%22+-%22%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C%22&lr=lang_uk) проти [46](//www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C%22+-%22%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%22&lr=lang_uk)) — незважаючи на те, що:

- *чистьте* зазначене прямо у § 81 правопису як приклад;
- щодо нього були неодноразові настанови мовознавців (Борис Рогоза [«Уроки державної мови»](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/194.htm), Євгенія Чак [«Складні питання граматики та орфографії»](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21552) тощо).

На мій погляд, українцям не подобається збіг приголосних (навіть коли наголос на основі).

#### Висновки

Особиста моя думка могла би бути такою:

> <sub>Закінчення *-и* в кінці цих слів мені видається припустимим орфографічним варіантом. Я би віддавав це на відкуп чуттю милозвучності мовця і, можливо, стилістистичним радникам — а не жорстко нормував. (Аналогічно я би не нормував жорстко використання *-и* в частках *б/би* так, як це робить правопис у § 82.)</sub>
>
> <sub>А вимога щодо *збільште*, *зменште* і *чистьте* (замість *збільшість*, *зменшіть*, *чистіть*) мені видається взагалі застарілою. Скільки людей не «катували» ще з часів СРСР, щоби вони писали *чистьте*, багато хто все одно пише *чистіть*. Мабуть, скупчення приголосних певного виду на кінці основи є припустимим виправданням для того, щоби вставити голосну на початку закінчення (навіть коли наголос на основі, а не на закінченні).</sub>

Але я недостатньо компететний, щоби робити такі висновки. Це винятково особиста точка зору непрофесіонала, що вміє користуватися пошуковими системами, але не має жодного стосунку до мовознавства. Я жодним чином не агітую за таку позицію.

А як правильно за правописом, зазначено в розділі «Правопис» цієї відповіді.

<sub>Інші обговорення:</sub>

- <sub>[«Наказова форма дієслова "збільшити" у множині...» на proz.com](http://www.proz.com/forum/ukrainian/97651-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%83_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96.html).</sub>
- <sub>[«Засвідчте - засвідчіть, підтвердьте - підтвердіть» на ГП](http://www.trworkshop.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=33914).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Звичайно існує, це наказовий спосіб 2-ї особи однини від дієслова *збільшити*.

> Збільши швидкість, Уоше, пожерачі нас наздоганяють! (телесеріал «Світлячок»)

Comment: Також у формі «збільш»: «[Не виконуючи ніяких записів, збільш це число на 12 і покажи відповідь.](//books.google.com/books?id=JWWhXDKXXtoC&q=%22збільш%22)»

Comment: @Sasha Як раз щодо цієї форми нема питань, саме вона подається у словнику як єдиний "наказовий спосіб":  (нажаль [нема прямого лінку](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)) та [тут](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%C7%C1%B2%CB%DC%D8%C8%D2%C8).

Comment: @Artemix, хм, справді, за правописом [не мало б бути «и»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par81p2b). Трапляння в гугл-книжках вкрай рідкі (більшість [тут](//www.google.com/search?q=%22збільши%22) хибнопозитивні), але є такі: [1](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22А+тоді+збільши.+Мені+потрібне+тільки+його+погруддя%22), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=mK8bAAAAMAAJ&q=%22збільши%22), [3](//books.google.com/books?id=DCUaAQAAIAAJ&q=%22збільши%22), [4](//books.google.com/books?id=FboWAQAAMAAJ&q=%22збільши%22) — це повний перелік.

Comment: Схожа ситуація з деякими іншими словами, наприклад [`залишити`](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/110445/40-Romaniuk.pdf): [`залиш`](http://nashe.com.ua/song/4292) або [`залиши`](http://nashe.com.ua/song/11759). Схоже, тут роль милозвучності, або ж твердості наказу на `ш`.

Comment: @Follower, мені теж здається, що «збільш»/«збільши», «залиш»/«залиши» — це більше питання милозвучності, аніж «одне — правильно, інше — ні». Але поки що підтверджень не знайшов. Правопис, як я вже казав, предписує без «и», але правопис і «б»/«би» в наступному параграфі жорстко нормує (що, по-моєму, нонсенс, по-моєму, це має лишатися на відкуп чуттю мовця).

Comment: [Тут цікаве обговорення](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/809456.html) і trina_ka стверджує, що *правопис однозначно каже, шо має бути без кінцевого **-и***

Comment: @Yola, так, я про це писав [вище](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1124#comment2937_1126) — при буквальній трактовці [правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par81p2b) виявляється, що казати «збі́льши» не можна (або «збільш», або, в крайньому разі, «збільши́»). Але на 100% довіряти тому правилу я би не став; як і наступному параграфу про «б»/«би». По-моєму, це насправді на смак мовця: частіше «я б пішов», але «я би пішов» забороняти якось дивно (частіше «зменш», але «зме́нши» забороняти якось дивно).

Comment: @Yellow Sky, дякую за цитату із "Світлячка", посміхнуло <3